# Background Job at time to time in React native

Tags: android, react-native

```
const mainStack = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen : {screen : Home},
  ViewScreen: {screen : ViewImages},
  ViewScreenServer: {screen : ViewImagesServer},
  FinalScreen: {screen : Final},

},{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
    header: null,
  }),

})

async connect = (data,tag) =>{
  RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://192.168.0.76/survey/upload_image.php', {
    Authorization: "Bearer access-token",
    otherHeader: "foo",
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  }, [
      { name: 'image', filename: 'image.png', type: 'image/png', data: data },
      { name: 'image_tag', data: tag }
    ]).then((resp) => {
      //Alert.alert("succsessfully uploaded to server");
    }).catch((err) => {
     Alert.alert("Some Error occured;");
    })
}

const backgroundJob = {
 jobKey: "myJob",
 period: 11000,
 allowExecutionInForeground:true,
 allowWhileIdle: true,
 job: () => {
   Alert.alert("Transferring data to server");
   let realm = new Realm();
   let result = realm.objects('fields');
   for(let i = 0 ; i < result.length; i++){

                   this.connect(result[i].data,result[i].tag);

   }
    realm.write(() => {
     realm.delete(data)
   })
 }
};

BackgroundJob.register(backgroundJob);

var backgroundSchedule = {
 jobKey: "myJob",
 period: 11000
}

BackgroundJob.schedule(backgroundSchedule);

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(mainStack)
export default AppNavigator;
```

Above file is AppNavigator.js file which contains a stack for application and a background job which should run at every 11 seconds.I put 11 seconds just for testing purpose.But above code doesn't works.Why?Every 11 sec it should run that task but it never runs.What i want to do is move all data from local realm database to mysql on remote server when user is connected to internet.